# Java platform independent encryption

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I am currently using Jasypt for my web application. It works fine, but the encryption is different depending which server it is hosted on.

For this reason, I can't just get the data in the live DB and use it for debugging in my dev environment. It would be helpful, but I can live without it.

What worries me is that at the moment I am using a hosting provider. All has been ok so far, but I worry that if at some point they replace the server, or move my application on to another one, the encrypted data ( such as emails and passwords for the login, and more ) will not be encrypted in the same way and all the data will become unusable.

Does anybody know an alternative to Jasypt which is platform independent?

Or is there a way to make Jasypt itself platform independent?

Thanks, Dan

PS : I would need a method that has these basic functionalities: string encryption ( reversible ), password encryption ( not reversible but comparable ) and "SHA-1" encryption. Apologies if the terminology in the last paragraph is not the most correct, but I am not an encryption expert at all.

Thanks!

Edited to add code, results and exceptions:

```
public class Test
{
      public static void main ( String [] args )
      {
        System.out.println ( "String encryption   = " + new EncryptionUtil ( ).encryptString ( "test string" ) );

        System.out.println ( "Password encryption = " + new EncryptionUtil ( ).encryptPassword ( "test password" ) );
        }
}
```

produces this in the dev environment :

```
String encryption   = ybXukKBN57QSY8ITPgu9RmJQrZP4Py6g
Password encryption = nNX82PuKx5TrqBFSCy6yzNpco7Asov2S
```

Everytime the output is different, but it is possible to decrypt the string, and compare the password by doing this:

```
public class Decryption
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        System.out.println ( new EncryptionUtil ( ).decryptString ( "ybXukKBN57QSY8ITPgu9RmJQrZP4Py6g" ) );

        System.out.println ( new EncryptionUtil ( ).passwordsMatch ( "test password", "nNX82PuKx5TrqBFSCy6yzNpco7Asov2S" ) );
    }
}
```

Which gives this output:

```
test string
true
```

This is the encryption util class that I created:

```
public class EncryptionUtil 
{
    private String password = "<<=Encryption-Password=>>";
    // ============================================================ Encrypt password string
    public String encryptPassword ( String pwd )
    {
        if ( null != pwd && ! "".equals ( pwd ) )
        {
            return new BasicPasswordEncryptor ().encryptPassword ( pwd );
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    // ====================================== Check if password entered matches that stored
    public boolean passwordsMatch ( String enteredPassword, String storedPassword )
    {
        return new BasicPasswordEncryptor().checkPassword ( enteredPassword, storedPassword );
    }

    //===================================================================== Encrypt string
    public String encryptString ( String text )
    {
        if ( null != password && ! "".equals ( password ) )
        {
            BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
            textEncryptor.setPassword ( password );
            return textEncryptor.encrypt ( text );
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    // ===================================================================== Decrypt string
    public String decryptString ( String text )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( null != text && ! "".equals ( text ) )
            {
                BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
                textEncryptor.setPassword ( password );
                return textEncryptor.decrypt ( text );
            }
           else
           {
                return "";
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        return text;
    }
}

    // =============== Encrypt email. Used for login and registration only, not decryptable
    public String encryptEmail ( String email )
    {
        if ( null != email && ! "".equals ( email ) )
        {
            return new String ( new Digester("SHA-1").digest ( email.getBytes () ) );
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

The same in the LIVE environment gives me this:

```
String encryption   = L/UlkJjYhLnYiov7XeDjb9W7+k8Gduvz
Password encryption = P+LJM7VJHu/hudSQOrmvcvV/DrzCv+pj
```

When I try to decrypt the string and check the password, I get this:

```
public class Decryption
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        System.out.println ( new EncryptionUtil ( ).decryptString ( "L/UlkJjYhLnYiov7XeDjb9W7+k8Gduvz" ) );

        System.out.println ( new EncryptionUtil ( ).passwordsMatch ( "test password", "P+LJM7VJHu/hudSQOrmvcvV/DrzCv+pj" ) );
    }
}
```

The result with the strings obtained from LIVE ( those above ) gives this:

test string
false

This time the encryption of the string works ( I had it not working in the past, I am a bit surprised and confused to be honest ), but the password fails.

---

New edit - some strings, when encrypted, end with ==. The strings that do not have "==" at the end, are decryptable across systems. Those which do do not work. Maybe this can be a clue?

Comment: Before you abandon Jasypt, is it possible your problems are caused by factors external to Jasypt? One common item that varies between platforms is default charsets - perhaps something is going wrong when converting between byte arrays and strings? Can you tell us more about how it doesn't work in your dev environment?

Comment: Need more info, what ciphers and modes are being used, what hash functions, what inputs are you giving what are you getting, what do you expect,what errors are you getting if any. This question begs for an SSCCE (http://sscce.org).

Comment: @DuncanJones Apologies if I wasn't clear - everything works fine both in DEV and LIVE, but the strings encrypted in one cannot be used in the other - which means the encryption is different. My concern is that it means that if something changes in the Live environment then all the encryption won't be usable and, because of that, the logins and all that lost.

Comment: @Dev Thank you for the sscce.org link, I wasn't aware of that. I am creating an example now and I will add it to the main question.

Comment: @Dan That sounds more like an [tag:character-encoding] issue than a [tag:encryption] issue as Duncan suggested. Encryption in Java always works in byte arrays, so unless Jasypt always uses the default encoding, the encryption routines should not be the issue.

Comment: Then again: `BasicTextEncryptor` has an (unspecified in the *public* documentation) static field: `private static final String MESSAGE_CHARSET = "UTF-8";`. So given just a string the character encoding is always UTF-8. Fortunately the lib is open source (compare e.g. with Microsoft where finding the character encoding is impossible without signing your own gag order).

Comment: @owlstead I posted the code and the results. I am a bit surprised that in this case the string decryption works - a few times in the past it didn't. However, the password comparison ( plain text against the encrypted one stored in the db ) still fails. If in the EncryptionUtil class I can add something to make it work all the time, I am very happy to stick to Jasypt really

Comment: @Dan I don't think there is any reason for now to switch... But it is extremely strange that you get a good decryption sometimes, and sometimes not. That points to input related issues. Note that SHA-1 *encryption* does not exist, SHA-1 is a hashing function. And the encrypt email functionality fails every encoding/decoding test and will create invalid results.

Comment: Do you maybe use the encrypted strings inside an URL? Because a GET request in HTTP should not contain the `'='`, `'+'` or `'/'` characters. You need to either use URL encoding for the base 64 encoded results, replace these characters by other ones (see [base64url on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)) or use hexadecimal output instead.

Comment: @owlstead all the data is POSTed from the form, never in a URL. As for the SHA-1 function: It is something I thought for the login. Since the same string ( email in this case ) is always encrypted with a different value, I save it as encrypted in a column for when I need to use it unencrypted, and hash it ( constant result ) in another column. So I can hash the email entered in the login page, "select record where hashed_stored_email = hashed_entered_email". Then I check if the password is correct on that single record. Maybe horrible, but it works

Comment: Maybe so, but `new Digester("SHA-1").digest` returns a set of random looking bytes bytes. If these bytes contain values that cannot be converted to characters then *you loose data*. And `email.getBytes()` uses the platform specific encoding. This means that the result may be different on different platforms, e.g. on your test and live machines.

Comment: @owlstead I am not really sure what was wrong... However, changing the password for the text encryptor solved the odd problem across environments, which I had for a long time. I am really sorry for having taken your time with this, I hadn't thought this random solution before and I can't understand why it worked. Please accept my apologies for having involved you in this. If nothing else, there was something wrong for real, not just in my head...

Comment: @Dan please learn from this that you cannot just swap characters and byte arrays. They are not the same thing, and you can run into incompatibility issues if you use default character encoding schemes. For sure you still need to fix your digester issue. It may randomly fail.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem was - anyway I managed to solve it with a random attempt which somehow worked...

If anybody finds him / her self in the same situation, an attempt ( lucky random one in my case ) is to change the password used for the text encryptor.

I cannot give any explanation on why it worked.

Answer (score -2):

You should take a look at [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)

There´s an example [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/encrypting-decrypting-text-messages-with-bouncy-castle-crypt.html)

Comment: I will only manage to take a look at it in a couple of hours, then I will accept your answer. But thanks so much for such a quick reply!

Comment: Bouncy Castle has hundreds of classes for many use cases. It is not an easy to use container like Jasypt. **Just** pointing to Bouncy is never a good answer really, unless it is already clear which functionality is needed.

Comment: Holger, I did take a look at BouncyCastle, but I am not sure that it is what I need... Lack of straight forward easy to follow examples or tutorials ( at least for my extremely limited knowledge on the matter ) make it a bit inaccessible for me... But thanks anyway!